# Is it possible to preload an assembly in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app in which I have a lot of references and the load time was not acceptable to me. I have removed the splash screen image and created an animated loading screen by having a separate project with no reference to the main application which then navigates to the first page of the rest of the app. It does start up fast now but it's a little lacking still.

I would like to do another animation right before the load screen goes away. The only way I can think of to do this is to actually preload the assemblies needed for the navigation to the next page, do an animation, and then navigate.

I have tried

- `OnNavigatedFrom` but the animation doesn't have time to run since the page will be replaced by the new page very quickly from that point.
- `OnNavigatingFrom` is no help either as it is called as soon as I call `NavigationService.Navigate();`
- Searching the web and Stack Overflow :)
- I also considered faking it a bit by having the next page show a duplicate of the load screen and do the last animation there, but it can't match the current state of the load screen animation and is harder to maintain

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can preload by just creating a new instance of the page you are going to navigate to. Unfortunately that has to be done on the UI thread which can cause animation slowdown, at least in my experience.

Here is a sample of how to do an animation, then preload, then do another animation before navigating. :

```
public partial class LoadScreen : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public LoadScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        // create your animation here

        sb.Completed += (sender, args) => PreLoad();
        sb.Begin();
    }

    private void PreLoad()
    {
        // this is the part that actually takes time and causes things to get loaded
        // you may need it in a try/catch block depending on what is in your constructor
        var page = new PageToNavigateTo();

        // now create an animation at the end of which we navigate away
        var sbOut = new Storyboard();
        // create your animation here

        sbOut.Completed += (sender, args) => NavigateToNextScreen();
        sbOut.Begin();
    }

    private void NavigateToNextScreen()
    {
        // navigate here
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        // remove the loading screen from the backstack so the user doesn't see it again when hitting the back button
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the loading of an assembly, just reference a type from this assembly.

For instance, something like `Console.WriteLine(typeof(YourAssembly.SomeType));` will force the loading of `YourAssembly`.

Now for your problem, maybe you can use usercontrols? Put the content of your main page in a user control. Display the loading page, create the usercontrol in the background, let the animation play, then when the animation is done playing replace the page's content with the usercontrol.

Comment: I tested your idea here but it appears that the assembly is loaded at startup rather than only when the line is executed. The usercontrol idea is a good one but does not fit what I'm trying to do. Thanks though!