# Preload UI Control when app starts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 application and I'm going to use a Bing Maps Control.

My problem is that when I navigate to a page with this control it gets too long to loads only on its first time.

I thought that I could load this UI Control on Start up (while Splash Screen is showing).

Can I do that? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never wrote anything for Microsoft's mobile platforms, but first thing coming to my mind would be removing the splash screen. Instead let the splash overlap the map control and everything else. Then just hide it once loading is done (and the set time has passed)?

As an alternative, you could try the preloading code shown in [one of the answers to this (similar) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314930/is-it-possible-to-preload-an-assembly-in-windows-phone-7).